# How do you replace the FK naming convention in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, naming-conventions, entity-framework-6

I've created a custom naming convention for foreign keys and can add it to the conventions:

```
builder.Conventions.Add(new UnderscorelessForeignKeyNamingConvention());
```

For the code below

```
class Address { City City { get; set; } }
```

I get `City_Id` column not found. What combination of `Add`, `Add<>`, and `Remove<>` calls on `builder.Conventions` would remove the existing naming convention or effectively allow mine to be considered first?

I've looked through the conventions under the debugger and documention, and it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Generated foreign key columns are referred to as Independent associations by EntityFramework.  Since these columns are generated by EntityFramework as it build the model these columns will not be accessible from custom conventions and it is necessary to use Model based conventions. This is the problem that you are running into with the convention above.

Model based conventions are [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439) In the documentation there is a [specific example about detecting and renaming independent association columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439#example2).  Once you write a convention that does this, you should simply need to add it to the conventions list.